# How to download images in stacks

Tags: jquery, web, developer-tools

I'm trying to download images from source. It is in stacks.
https://radiopaedia.org/cases/ct-abdomenpelvis-upper-axial-labelling-questions

I've tried to use inspect element function in firefox developer tools, and it seems that path to the file changes every time I scroll

```
<img style="height: 610px; width: 610px; position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 0px;" id="offline-workflow-study-large-image" src="https://prod-images.static.radiopaedia.org/images/12503836/17780c2c930680dd5c9e9a95f1ca58_big_gallery.jpg">
```

this is what i get. but I would like to get whole images/.../..._big_gallery.jpg part

Thank you in adevance

Comment: Do you mean that the source of the image files are not the same? If so, it might be how the files are actually held. And it may have nothing to do with you scrolling.

Comment: I mean, I would like to download the stack of image file`s`, but when i track the image location, it shows only one location of an image - the one that is currently on the screen. but I would like to get all the files' location that are hidden